# Doxygen: specify layout per file

Tags: doxygen

I would like to change the page layout for a single source file. The other pages should be generated as before.
Other option would be to generate a seperate page referencing the relevant content from that source file.

To make it a little more concrete, I have the following file and would like to generate a documentation file only including these comments without the printing of includes, etc.
And as said this behavior is only intended for this single source file.

/**
* TreeNode
*xxx
*/
class TreeNode

/**
* TreeNode2
*xxx
*/
class TreeNode2

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Other option could be to include a brief description via a \ref command. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best approach is to exclude the bits you *don't* want by surrounding those parts in the file with `@cond` and `@endcond` markers.  (The `#if 0` of doxygen.)

In that way your file processing won't be complicated with file-specific layouts (which I'm not sure is possible anyway) and the 'special' handling of that file is visible within that file's content.